# ¿Cómo agregar una observación en una ubicación específica de un vector o marco de datos en R?

Tags: r

Estoy creando una variable dummy de control que toma el valor de 1 cada vez que el valor de cambio supera el 30%, dado que estoy trabajando com el cambio la longitud de el vector me queda menor a el resto de variables en 1. Necesito incertar en la primera observacion de control el valor de 0:

```
control1<-as.vector(ifelse(abs(kdhis)>0.3,1,0))

 *control1= c(0,1,0,0,1)
```

y necesito que quede:

```
 *control1= c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Traduce tu pregunta, estás en versión en español de SO de otra manera será cerrada

Comment: No logro entender por que necesitas insertar un elemento nuevo al vector, de cualquier forma, hacerlo es sencillo `control1 <- c(0, control1)`. Saludos.

Comment: Patricio, Justo lo que necesitaba, Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la función append()

> control1<-c(0,1,0,0,1)
>
> append(control1, 0, 0)

Donde el primer parámetro es el vector, el segundo el valor a agregar, el tercero la posición (si no la colocas lo agrega en la última posición)